# Windows | Two audio streams from movie through different audio outputs?

Tags: audio, sync, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

I have an issue where I want to output different audio streams from a movie to different outputs. One audio stream is the original movie audio, the other is a dubbed translated version.

My PC is connected via HDMI to my TV, so ideally I'd like to send the original audio through HDMI and the dubbed audio stream through the headphone jack, but I could deal with other methods as well.

I tried multicasting the movie and watching the stream through my TV PC for original audio, and watching the stream through a phone or different laptop for the dubbed version - but as the movie file is a bluray, my main PC can't handle the file and clients can't handle the quality as well.

I also tried using Syncplay, and it kind of worked, but it was very hard to adjust the delay between devices, and after pausing the main video it was a pain to get everything up and running again.

Maybe someone has an idea of what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc), you can control it using an Android device connected through WiFi to your LAN. There are some apps you can use, like [VLCDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlcforandroid.vlcdirectprofree) with VLC as target. From your android device you can open discs in your drive and change audios, subtitles, etc. You will also need to [configure your VLC](http://vlcdirectprofreescript.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/vlcdirectbat-script-windows-only.html) .

[image]

With [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/) you can do it too (for example, using [Remote for MPC LITE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=media.misc) but you have got many you can use). You will need to activate web interface:

[image]